# What is the easiest way to generate an App.Config file through pure c# code

Tags: c#

I know the easiest way to generate a config file is through visual studio. however the environment my program is going to be functioning in we are going to have several different configurations and the application needs to be able to build the config files on its own. Just curious if there is an easier way than making a large string literal and then copying over to a new file. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does it have to be an actual App.Config file, or can you just serialize some classes?

Comment: Use `XElement`.

Comment: @SLaks: context?

Comment: @Robert Harvey yes, additional info right fast. The location the application is being hosted out of is going to have access to every user. and on the off chance that it gets deleted I would like for the program to create it itself.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to provide some sensible protection for App.Config?  Anyway, it's just an XML file.  As SLaks pointed out in his cryptic way, you can manipulate it or create it in the same way you would any other XML file.

Comment: You can also simply store a string literal in your program and write it out to a file in the usual way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you would think I would do the sensible thing. unfortunately that cant be the case as there are a lot of factors and just building a new one is the easiest route to take. I appreciate the help. I guess ill just continue on the manual writing to file path I was on. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what kind of information you want to save in generated configurations.

If you are using only appSettings section which as only key values, then it would be better to generate a JSON file.   It is very easy to generate it using newtonsoft.json.

in your app.config file you can keep the path of JSON file and load the settings at app startup if the file is already available.

**NOTE:**
JSON can also store any kind of complex configurations, you will have to generate the classes to hold those configurations. 
Once you application puts value in these objects, serialize it to JSON and keep it in appropriate folder which is accessible to application.

Hope this helps.